# xalan error messages despite using "saxon=true" in ServiceMix 6.1.4 with Camel 2.16.5

Tags: apache-camel, xslt-2.0, saxon, apache-servicemix

I am trying to do XSLT 2.0 using a blueprint route in Apache ServiceMix 6.1.4.
The camel-saxon feature is already installed and active. The xslt file is embedded in blueprint like this:

`<toD uri="xslt:path_to_xsl?saxon=true"/>`

The blueprint route deploys without any problems, but as soon as an exchange body arrives at the xsl component i get a xalan error. Xalan obviously complains about an invalid xsl (because it is not able to parse xslt 2.0). But why is xalan used when I explicitly told the component to use saxon? What am I missing and how can I get the xslt component to work with saxon and xslt 2.0?

Comment: Try with a newer version of ServiceMix / Karaf / and also outside OSGi. Also try to restart ServiceMix, it can be about classloading issue, or refresh bundles etc.

Comment: You may also want to try adding `transformerFactoryClass=net.sf.saxon.TransformationFactory` instead of `saxon=true`.

Comment: I have tried all of this. Restarting won't help, refreshing bundles and clearing cache won't either. ServiceMix 7.0.x and 7.1.x behave the same way. Adding `transformerFactoryClass=net.sf.saxon.TransformationFactory` instead of `saxon=true` is also not helping.

Comment: Also there is no error message about xslt not finding saxon. It seems like the option for using it is just ignored.

Comment: No idea if this is relevant, but have you tried to use `.to()` instead of `.toD()`? Given that you have only one stylesheet, the endpoint in your question is static so you don't need `.toD()`

Comment: I narrowed down the issue. In our setup the xsl file is located on a web server. So 'path_to_xsl' is actually a http-address. So when the blueprint file is parsed the parameter `?saxon=true` is actually interpreted as a part of the http-url and not as a uri-parameter for the xslt component. Any ideas on how to work around that? The official camel xslt site states `xslt:http:` as supported format, so is there any way to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I narrowed down the issue. In our setup the xsl file is located on a web server, which means `path_to_xsl` is actually a http-address. When the blueprint file is parsed the parameter `?saxon=true` is actually interpreted as a part of the http-url and not as a uri-parameter for the xslt component. If i use a local file path instead of the web url the saxon component is working fine. So actually the problem is within the uri parsing algorithm in `org.apache.camel.component.xslt.XsltComponent` and its `org.apache.camel.util.ResourceHelper`. There the parameters are added to the http uri and afterwards cleared, so they will never show as uri parameters for the endpoint.